# Why symmetry leads to stability?

Tags: symmetry, everyday-life, equilibrium, stability

In the whole course of physics I observed a very common thing present around us which is **symmetry**. Symmetry leads to stability everywhere. For example:-Pauli's Exclusion principle tends to make the electronic distribution symmetrical in orbitals. Next example is the non-symmetrical distribution of materials In earth's core leads to instability of earth. In general symmetry leads to stability in nature.

I want to ask why nature prefers symmetrical systems over non symmetrical systems?

Comment: I think I disagree with your premise that more symmetrical systems tend to be more stable. For a counterexample, if I have a ferromagnetic material, formed of a collection of magnetic dipoles, the system is initially rationally symmetric. The lowest energy configuration, however has all the dipoles aligned in some direction (although there is no reason to pick one direction over another). This means that you need to break your initial symmetry to find the most stable configuration.

Comment: @By Symmetry Hi Is universe symmetrical about a point? As it is stable so I think that it must be symmetrical!

Comment: One line of reason goes as follows: _Symmetry constrains a system. With enough symmetry you might end up with a unique solution..._

Comment: @Qmechanic♦ would you please quote it as an answer?

Comment: Where do you see symmetry in the solar system? Or stability for that matter? Nature tends to be mostly unstable and asymmetric.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how this could be generalised to all cases, but in most of the cases where I have noticed, symmetry leads to stability because there is no reason to prefer one over another.

For example, a vertical tower is rotationally symmetric about the ground, while a leaning tower is not. The leaning tower falls in the direction that it leans over to, but the vertical tower leans equally in all directions, and hence there is no direction to fall to.

Similarly, for diffusion, when there is more of one gas at one place than another, it is more likely that the gas leaves that place rather than enter. When diffusion is complete, the distribution of gases is (macroscopically) translationally and rotationally symmetric.

As a way to use symmetry to locate equilibrium points, here is an example. If a terrain is shaped like a cosine wave, even if **know nothing about how a cosine wave looks**, I could deduce from the fact that it is symmetric about the y-axis to conclude that the y-intercept is an equilibrium point (because the tangent at that point cannot lean to the right or left, it should be symmetric, and hence it can only be straight up or flat, and a straight up tangent would mean that there is more than one cosine for a given angle)

To put this in a better way, if the law of cause-and-effect is true (i.e., effects are uniquely determined by causes) and the causes have a symmetry, then the **effect should also have that symmetry**. Otherwise, I could change the outcome by applying that symmetry to the causes, leaving the causes unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Symmetry breaking]

This here is a symmetric potential yet at the Symmetry it is not stable in order to be in stable equilibrium configuration it has to break this Symmetry, so it's not necessary that symmetries will give a stable configuration, but we see symmetries around us because there exists a infinitesimal Symmetry (in its neighbourhood) around a stable configuration, which is why something is at equilibrium, but unstable equilibrium also have symmetries, so symmetries and stability are not necessarily conjugate,

If something is stable there will be some Symmetry in its neighbourhood, but symmetry in neighbourhood doesn't imply stable condition it can be unstable as well,

But symmetries do lead to some conserved quantities.